# pubnub.com and pusher.com - does it send push notification to mobile?

Tags: objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

How does it work? do these service also send push notification to a mobile device iphone/android? (even if the device is switched off?)

Comment: who voted for close? why close it, what is wrong with the question?

Answer (score 2):

> How does it work?

PubNub focus on HTTP connectivity (streaming, long-polling, polling etc.) that will work on all devices and anywhere.

Pusher use WebSocket between the client (web browser, mobile, tablet, desktop, any web-enabled device) and their service. They offer HTTP fallback for older devices or on networks that interfere with WebSocket connectivity.

> do these service also send push notification to a mobile device iphone/android?

Both services support the ability to push data from one device to another via their service. This functionality is not the same type of functionality as Apple Push Notifications (APN), Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) or Microsoft Notification Protocol (MNP).

Only PubNub support native Push Notifications.

PubNub offer a larger number of [client SDKs](https://www.pubnub.com/developers/).

[Pusher](http://pusher.com) have a number of [client libraries](http://pusher.com/docs/libraries) for mobile devices including Android and iPhone (iOS).

> (even if the device is switched off?)

PubNub offer a form of message history for messaging delivered by mobile/web data connectivity. So upon reconnection missed messages will be delivered.

Pusher do not presently offer this functionality. So any messages that are sent during periods where the client is disconnected are lost.

If you use PubNub and their native Push Notification support then you get the delivery guaranteed by the underlying notification network that's used (Apple, Google or Microsoft).

Comment: "Whilst both of these services will let you add push notifications to a mobile application" is push notification built in or it has to be added separately?

Comment: Push notification functionality is performed over a web connection and not through the native network mechanism e.g. APN.

Comment: But are those notifications sent by Pusher or PubNub look like an actual APNS while the application is in background ?

Comment: Since writing this answer PubNub now offer native push notification integration http://www.pubnub.com/how-it-works/mobile/

Comment: I don't think pusher offers the type of push notifications you are expecting. See here: https://support.pusher.com/hc/en-us/articles/203902316-Sending-push-notifications-using-Pusher