# Pusher iOS Apple Service

Tags: ios, objective-c, pusher

is it possible to use the Pusher-Service with my .p12-certificate like Urbanairship?

I'd like to trigger my messages from ruby or something else with Pusher and use the Apple-embeded Push-Notifications
Would be great.
Otherwise I have to use Urbanairship.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pusher is to communicate between an app (native or web) which listen to a channel, but you can not send off line notification using pusher.

Look at [pubnub.com and pusher.com - does it send push notification to mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9137735/pubnub-com-and-pusher-com-does-it-send-push-notification-to-mobile)